# Angular 2 and php Laravel 5 example

Tags: php, angular, laravel

I am trying to find a concrete example on how to use the Laravel with Angular 2. 
Tried using google, but no luck. Additionally, I was wondering when using the Component annotation object key templateUrl, can it accept php extension instead of html.

Comment: I am not talking about angular 1 working with  laravel.

Comment: Yes, sorry bout` that

Comment: angular doesn't care what language or framework your back end uses. There is no relationship between them, only the data that is transferred between server and client

Answer (score 0):

The consensus appears to be that it's best to use Angular 2 as an independent front-end, and have Laravel act as an API.

That said, I did find [this guide](https://www.codetutorial.io/laravel-5-and-angular-2-beta-setup/) that definitely links the two.  I'm not sure if it will answer your specific question, but it might help you get started.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

After setup all router in front-side with angular.

*This route is for Angular2 and it should be place after all other backend routes
just keep it at the bottom* ( *route.php* in laravel5.2 *web.php* in laravel5.3)

```
Route::get('/{any}', function ($any) {
return view('welcome');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$scope.refresh = function () {
    $http({
      url: '',
      method: "GET"

    }).success(function (data) {
      $scope.trans = data.transactions; 
     console.log($scope.trans);

    }).error(function (data) {
      console.log('Error');
    });
 }
$scope.refresh(); // We call the function on initialization to load the feed.
```

Comment: While the code may answer the question you should explain it.